# What Is this C# Code doing in algorithms?

Tags: c#, syntax, nlp-question-answering

encoded Data = (encoded Data | bit Shift Buffer)

Comment: the ** is not important,         j = j+1 == key.Length ? 0 : j + 1;

Comment: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3A#C#) for the rescue! it's basically an inline-`if`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line:

```
j = j + 1 == key.Length ? 0 : j + 1;
```

could also be written as:

```
if ((j+1) == key.Length)
    j = 0;
else
    j = j+1;
```

Comment: you might want to fix that missing semicolon.

Comment: @JesseChunn I did it for them, simple type-o.

Comment: @Codexer ... wow, I just realized that I / you can edit other peoples answers. Scary, but cool.

Comment: @JesseChunn: with reputation comes power.  Each time you hit a specific reputation level you get another quantum of power. Codexer has nearly 7k of reputation, so there's lots of things he can do.  Folks with lots of reputation are trusted enough that the site knows if they edit a question or answer, then they aren't messing with the intent of the text, just making it better.